# Es posible crear una referencia a una clase en una propiedad estática?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, clase

Resulta que estoy trabajando con 2 formularios, que por detras son 2 subclases derivadas de la superclase `Form`, por eso el titulo de la pregunta.

En cada clase tengo una propiedad llamada `Instancia`:

```
public Form1 Instancia
{
   get => this;
}
```

Sin embargo, esto requiere que se instancie la clase `Form1` dentro de `Form2` para acceder a esta propiedad, y esto es un problema ya que al crear una instancia cíclica (`Form1` en `Form2` y a la vez `Form2` en `Form1`) es muy probable que se produzca una excepción de desbordamiento de pila (`StackOverflowException`)

Para solventar esto, prefiero evitar la instancia declarando mi propiedad como estática:

```
private static Form1 _Instancia = null;

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _Instancia = this;
}

public static Form1 Instancia
{
   get => _Instancia;
}

public void MiMetodo()
{
   
}
```

Así, en la clase `Form2` la referencia se simplifica a esto:

```
Form1.Instancia.MiMetodo();
```

Sin embargo, como ven, al principio, la propiedad `_Instancia` tiene un valor `null` puesto que en C#, la palabra clave `this` no se puede usar fuera de los métodos o el constructor; tampoco se puede usar `this` propiedades o métodos estáticos.

Esto produce una `NullReferenceException` en mi programa, ya que al iniciar, necesita acceder a `MiMetodo` en la clase de `Form1`, pero su instancia es `null` porque aún no se ha ejecutado el método `Form_Load`.

Y es que:

> Como `this` apunta a una instancia de la clase, en el método estático no tiene una instancia.
>
> La palabra clave `this` se refiere a la instancia actual de la clase. Las funciones de miembro estático no tienen este puntero.

Es posible hacer algo como esto?

Una propiedad estática que en el momento de su declaración ya contenga la instancia de la clase?

```
public static Instancia
{
   get => this; // Error
}
```

Comment: En principio, es un poco extraño lo que intentas, y no termino de entender que intentas conseguir. Pero intuyo que lo que quieres es que no se pueda cargar mas de una instancia de cada formulario. Si es asi, puedes implementar el patron Singleton, [mira esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1403626/579895)

Comment: Veo que ya has aceptado una respuesta pero aun así, has pensado en utilizar eventos? creo que sería lo ideal para tu caso.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano eventos?

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Como lo haria con eventos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Porqué tiene que ser en el load la inicializacion de la variable estática? Asignale valor en el constructor del formulario.

Si luego quieres / necesitas saber si ya está cargado el formulario:

```
if (Application.OpenForms().OfType<Form1>().Any())
{
    // el formulario ya está cargado
}
```

El this lo puedes usar en el constructor.